# Kryonet connection successful but not receiving messages

Tags: java, networking, kryonet

Hi I am using Kryonet as my network library for the game I'm developing.

I've got this code in the server side:

```
public class MyServer {
    Kryo kryo;
    Server server;
    Connection connection;
    public MyServer(){
        server = new Server();
        server.start();
        try {
            server.bind(59990, 59900);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR");
        }

        kryo = server.getKryo();
        kryo.register(Message.class);

        server.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void received (Connection con, Message str) {
                System.out.println("Message recieved from client to server");
                Message m = (Message)str;
                System.out.println(m.text);

            }
            public void connected(Connection con){
                System.out.println("Hey, we are connected!");
                connection = con;
                con.sendTCP("HOLA CLIENTE!!");
            }
            public void disconnected(Connection con){
                System.out.println(":( He is gone... he'll never come back..");
            }
        });

    }

    public void sendMessage(String tipoMensaje,String tipoTropa,String id){
        connection.sendTCP(tipoMensaje+"-"+tipoTropa+"-"+id);
    }

}
```

And this in the client side:

```
public class MyClient {
    Client client;
    Connection connection;
    Kryo kryo;
    public MyClient(){
        client = new Client();
        client.start();


        try {
            kryo = client.getKryo();
            kryo.register(Message.class);

            client.connect(5000, "10.211.55.3", 59990, 59900);
            //sendMessage("fromclient","ee","ee");

            client.addListener(new Listener() {
                public void received (Connection con, String str) {
                      System.out.println(str);

                      System.out.println("Message recieved from server to client");
                }
                public void connected(Connection con){
                    System.out.println("Hey, we are connected!");
                    connection = con;
                    Message m = new Message();
                    m.text="eeep";
                    client.sendTCP(m);
                }
                public void disconnected(Connection con){
                    System.out.println(":( He is gone... he'll never come back..");
                }
            });


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while connecting");
        }   


    }


    public void sendMessage(String tipoMensaje,String tipoTropa,String id){
        client.sendTCP(tipoMensaje+"-"+tipoTropa+"-"+id);
        System.out.println("Message sent from client to server");

    }
}
```

Message is just a class with a string in it. When I try to connect client to the server I get the "Hey, we are connected!" message and afterwards a "Message recieved from client to server" in the server's command line. However, m.text (the content of the message) is not printed and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's because there is no method `public void received (Connection con, String str)` in a Listener - basically, your server never calls it. This is also a reason why you should use `@Override` - you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

Replace `String str` with `Object o`. Then - check if your object is actually a `Message`. If it is, cast it to a `Message` and print out its text. Your method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void received(Connection connection, Object packet) {
    if (packet instanceof Message) {
        System.out.println(((Message) packet).text);
    }
}
```